# How can i set background inside responsive div?

Tags: html, css

How can i set background inside responsive div?

I want to have inside that div plus sign (font awesome).

Problem is next:

- I need to set `height` if I want to set background image, otherwise, div is invisible (when I set `height: auto`;);
- Second thing, if I set a fixed `height` (let's say, 200px), div is not responsive, logicaly;
- And third thing, if I fix that problem somehow, how can I set plus sign inside div verticaly and horizontaly in center?

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of setting the height in pixels, try using a percentage. That might help with your first two issues. You can use the "background-position" property to place the background where you'd like within the div: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp

Comment: Well, it doesn't help, i try everything. Thanks for answer.

Comment: Can you replicate your issue on a JSFiddle? @bostaq_sb9

Comment: I dont know how to use this stack overflow, it's so complicated. I will post the code.

Comment: go to http://jsfiddle.net/ and post the code that you're working with. You can then save, and post a link on here to the Fiddle. It makes it easier for us to see your code, and experience your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case you can use `%` values on padding and width to keep the aspect ratio relative to the parent, and use some absolute position for the Plus sign:

```css
div {
  width:50%;
  padding:25% 0;
  background:url('http://placehold.it/500') no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  position:relative;
}
div > span {
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  height:30px;line-height:30px;
  background:red;color:white;
  width:50%;text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div><span>PlusSign</span></div>
```

Comment: This can be good, i hope it is, but i already use similar stuff. I will try this and i will write you when i test it. Thanks bro. Hvala ti brate

Comment: @bostaq_sb9 Glad to help U mate

Answer (score 1):

If you want the + centered in a square, responsive box, here's how you could do that:

```css
div {
 width: 20%; 
 padding-bottom: 20%; 
 background: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-g-640-480-4.jpg) no-repeat; 
 background-size: cover; 
 position: relative;
}

p {
 font-size: 4em; 
 color: white; 
 margin: 0; 
 padding: 0; 
 font-weight: bold; 
 position: absolute; 
 top:50%;
 left:50%;
 -webkit-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
   transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  }
```

```html
<div><p>+</p></div>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

div {
    width: 20%; 
    padding-bottom: 20%; 
    background: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-g-640-480-4.jpg) no-repeat; 
    background-size: cover; 
    position: relative;
}

p {
    font-size: 4em; 
    color: white; 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    position: absolute; 
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    -webkit-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  }

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div><p>+</p></div>

</body>
</html>
```